# Asymptotic notation: A function is Θ-Notation

Tags: asymptotics

*H. Cormen, Exercise 3.1-2*

**The following statement is true? If yes, prove that it is true.**

$$
(n+a)^b = Θ(n^b)\\
a, b \in R\\
b>0
$$

I tried to expand $(n+a)^b$ using the Binomial theorem, but I couldn't solve this.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Notice that 
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{(n+a)^b}{n^b}=1,$$
hence there is some $n_0$ for which if $n\geqslant n_0$,
$$\frac 12 n^b\leqslant (n+a)^b\leqslant \frac 32 n^b.$$
This proves that for some $M$, the inequality
$$\frac 1M\leqslant \frac{(n+a)^b}{n^b}\leqslant M$$
holds for each $n\geqslant 1$.

More generally, if $(a_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$ and $(b_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$ are two sequences of positive numbers such that $(a_n/b_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$ converges to a positive number, then $a_n=\Theta(b_n)$.

Comment: When you say "sequence of positive numbers" you mean "positive function", right?

Comment: Yes (actually a sequence is a function from the natural numbers to the real line).

Comment: How do you found $3/2$ and $1/2$ ?

Comment: I picked $\varepsilon:=1/2$ in the definition of a limit.

Comment: ε ? What does it means?

Comment: The $\varepsilon$ in the definition of a limit. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_%28mathematics%29#Limit_of_a_sequence.

Comment: It's not clear why you picked $1/2$ =(

Comment: It's an arbitrary choice.

Comment: I am sorry. It must be easy but I cannot see what is happening here. Could you explain it?

Answer (score 0):

for $n>a \ (n+a)^b = (n(1+\frac{a}{n}))^b = O(n^b) \cdot O(1)$. From this you can easily deduce the lower bound.

Comment: Is it right: $n>a(n+a)^b$ ?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, but using Bernoulli's inequality it'easy to see for example that $(1+\frac{a}{n})^b >1+\frac{ab}{n} = O(1)$

Comment: You said: $n>a(n+a)^b$ but there isn't $a$ that mutiplies $(n+a)^b$. This statement is wrong, I guess. Even so, $n>(n+a)^b$ <= This is not true.

Comment: oh no what I meant is that for $n>a$ the following statement holds. It's just a blank space between $a$ and the bracket)

Comment: There is a step between $n^b(1+a/n)^b$ and $O(n^b).O(1)$ that's not so intuitive. Where $O(1)$ came out?

Comment: If $a$ is a positive constant then $(1+\frac{a}{n})>1 = \Omega(1)$ and you can pick a constant larger than 1 s.t. $1+\frac{a}{n} = O(1)$. The same logic applies if $a$ is negative. $O(1)$ means a constant.